# Powershell recursive filename read and rename

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

i have downloaded from my ftp server a directory tree using wget and forcing ascii encoding so now i hve a lot of folders and files names something like "foo%C3%BC" (some of the files/folders already have correct names because they only had ascii characters).

I'm now trying toconvert them back to utf-8 using powershell, i tried writing the following line to accomplish this

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\folder -Recurse | select BaseName | Rename-Item -NewName {[System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlDecode{BaseName}}
```

but this is not working and gives me the following error

```
Rename-Item : Cannot rename because item at '@{BaseName=filename}' does not exist.
At line:1 char:88
+ ... ect BaseName | Rename-Item -NewName {[System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlDecode{BaseNam ...
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Rename-Item], PSInvalidOperationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand
```

over and over again (i suppose once for every file found).

The command works niecly up to the pipe after "select BaseName" so the problem is in the renaming part.

Does anyone have any idea how to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it with the following script

```
$data =  get-childitem C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\folder -recurse | Sort-Object FullName -descending;

ForEach($dat in $data){

    $decoded = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlDecode($dat.name);

    if ($dat.name -ne $decoded){ren $dat.FullName $decoded}

}
```

The if it's just to aoid the powershell throwing an erorr every time it finds a name that doesn't need conversion.

Comment: @Josh Lavely Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

```
  [Reflection.Assembly]::loadWithPartialName("System.Web") | out-null   
   $data =  Get-ChildItem C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\folder -Recurse 
   ForEach($dat in $data){
     $newName = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlDecode($dat.Name);
     $dat | Rename-Item -NewName $newName -Force
 }
```

Comment: Oh ok, ithought that the `Select BaseName` was necessary to pass it to the next stago in hte pipeline. Now i have anotherproblem, it tells me that `Cannot create a file when it already exist`. Have you any idea how i can make it work?

Comment: Nope, all properties from the parent pipeline are accessible all the way down.

Comment: This still doesn't work, not the error is `Rename-Item: Cannot evaluate parameter 'NewName' because its argument is specified as a script block and there is no input`

Comment: We seem to be moving in the right direction but it still doesn't work, now it says `Rename-Item : Cannot rename because item at 'Microsoft.Powershell.core\FileSytem::FILEPATH does not exist` so the path of the file is read correctly (not decoded). Also the first 2 subdirectories have been renamed to "BaseName"

Comment: Do the files/ folders you're trying to rename match what you expect them to be named, before the script is run? Meaning; did we already rename those and now it doesnt match what it expects?

Comment: i am working on a copy of the files so every time i run the script i delete it and start from fresh. right now i get th error i wrote and the first folder inside "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\folder" gets renamed to "BaseName" but nothing else changes

Comment: inside the loop can you print out ``` $dat | fl  ``` ? so as it runs we want to see all the properties foreach item, we want to verify its actually picking it up.

Comment: yeah that works, i get the path,  name, length and so on

Comment: So, i think i got this for you in a one-liner. It's still difficult to work with because i can't see what the start type is like. When you set the file name to BaseName you strip the extnsion. Is that what you wnt?

Comment: `
Get-ChildItem C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\folder -Recurse | foreach-Object {$_ | Rename-Item -NewName {[System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlDecode{$_.BaseName}}  }
`

Comment: wait, i don't think you understood what i need. i have this huge directory tree with URL encoded directory and file names, i need to rename all of them tu UTF-8. the BaseName thing was an error that it's not supposed to happen. The file types needs to remain the same just the name needs to change from E.G. M%C3%BCller to Müller

Comment: with the oneliner you just wrote on my computer the first folder alphabetically in each folder gets rename to $_.BaseName. I really have no idea what's going on xD

Comment: What OS are you running from?

Comment: windows server 2012 r2